# Are there any subtle differences between "de nuevo" and "otra vez"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

There are two very common ways in Spanish to say the equivalent of "again":

- *de nuevo*
- *otra vez*

But I use them pretty randomly because I've never been able to pick up on any differences in how native speakers use them. Are there any differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para salir de dudas, recurrí al Servicio de Consultas de la RAE y transcribo aquí la respuesta que recibí:

> En relación con su consulta, le remitimos la siguiente información:
>
> Ambas expresiones se emplean con el mismo sentido y en situaciones
>   semejantes, sin que quepa establecer diferencias. Tan solo en algunos
>   contextos solo se emplearía una, como en el caso de que, por ejemplo,
>   alguien muestre hastío ante la reiteración de alguien en alguna acción
>   o palabra; en este caso, solo se diría "¿Otra vez?", pero muy
>   raramente se diría "¿De nuevo?".
>
> Sin embargo, insistimos, se emplean con idéntico significado y en las
>   mismas condiciones.

Así que, las dos expresiones son completamente equivalentes, salvo en algunos contextos muy específicos, como el del ejemplo que aparece en el texto citado.

Answer (score 7):

I would say that "*de nuevo*" or "*nuevamente*" sounds more like "*all over again*", while "*otra vez*" is just "*again*".

Examples:

- Tengo que hacerlo de nuevo. — I have to do it all over again.
- Tengo que hacerlo otra vez. — I have to do it again.

As noted, these differences are very subtle, in many cases "*de nuevo*", "*nuevamente*" and "*otra vez*" can be used interchangeably. However in some cases "*de nuevo*" ("*nuevamente*") is used in meaning *"anew"*, then changing it for *"otra vez"* changes the meaning of the sentence slightly.

Comment: I don't agree with this. In your example, "de nuevo" and "otra vez" are completely interchangeable; only context will determine if the intended meaning is that of "all over again".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I do agree that they are very similar. But it you look at examples at http://spanish.about.com/cs/vocabulary/qt/againqt.htm, you'll see that these sentences will just not sound good if you exchange "de nuevo" for "otra vez". I do agree that other way around it works.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: actually native Spanish speaker (from Spain) would say exactly that. Example: http://www.atrapalo.com/viajes/index.php?pg=visor&ptv=como_funciona#pre09

Comment: +1 An example from https://diariodecuba.com/cuba/1663501344_42306.html *’Mi pareja me amenazó con no dejarme siquiera reconocer a mi futuro hijo, si no salgo nuevamente del bache. Y realmente no tengo las fuerzas suficientes para lidiar otra vez contra la adicción’* supports the usage described in this answer

Answer (score 4):

They are used pretty much interchangeably. Check this page, "*[Saying again in Spanish](http://spanish.about.com/cs/vocabulary/qt/againqt.htm)*", it has some examples.

There are some expressions in English where you would use "again", but that in Spanish change form or that are slightly different:

- **Never again** = *¡nunca más!* or *¡nunca jamás!*;
- **Again and again** = *una y otra vez*;
- **Now and again** (also **from time to time** / **every so often**) = *de vez en cuando*;
- **Then again** = *por otra parte* (synonym of *además* in this case).